# Cannot connect to SQL Server using pyodbc from another domain

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I'm trying to connect to it from another domain with this code below but I'm getting an error like this

> InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('28000', '[28000]
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed.
> The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with
> Integrated authentication. (18452) (SQLDriverConnect); [28000]
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed.
> The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with
> Integrated authentication. (18452)') (Background on this error at:
> http://sqlalche.me/e/13/rvf5)

This is my code that I'm using:

```
import pyodbc
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

server = 'shul'

database = 'db_pre'

uid = 'pre'
pwd = 'pr@20si'

engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://' + server + '/' + database + '/' + uid + '/' + pwd + '?trusted_connection=no&driver=ODBC+Driver+13+for+SQL+Server')

#engine = create_engine('mysql://root:@localhost/daming') # enter your password and database names here

col_names = ["month", "price", "change"]
df = pd.read_csv("kcl.csv",sep=',',quotechar='\'',encoding='utf8', names=col_names,skiprows = 1) # Replace Excel_file_name with your excel sheet name
df.to_sql('kcl',con=engine,index=False,if_exists='replace') # Replace Table_name with your sql table name
```

In SQL Server Management Studio I used SQL Server authentication instead of Windows Authentication.

Please help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The order of your `server`, `database`, `uid` and `pwd` doesn't look correct. I've put it in an f-string to try make it clearer. `f'mssql+pyodbc://{uid}:{pid}@{server}/{database}?driver=ODBC+Driver+13+for+SQL+Server;Trusted_Connection=no'`

Comment: Also just noticed the `@` in your password. If that is in your password it'll cause problems.

Comment: @PGHE thank you! but i still got the same error, im trying to change the pwd like this pwd = 'predik@2021si'.format(pwd='predikpwd') and yeah its still the same error

Comment: @adindaaulia 1) why such an old driver? Why not v. 17 ?2) the problem is caused by using a URL and SQL Alchemy, not PyODBC. [The pyodbc example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver15) doesn't use a URL

Comment: @adindaaulia if you use a URL from strings you need to ensure each part is URL-encoded. You can't just concatenate strings that may contain special characters like `@` or `/` or `#`. It's quite likely that an unexpected character made SQL Alchemy *ignore* the user/password pair and everything after it and connect using the default (and far more secure) mechanism, Windows Authentication

Comment: @adindaaulia `yeah its still the same error ` because it's still the same string. `@` still becomes part of the URL. Store the string in a separate variable and inspect it before passing it to `create_engine`

Comment: thank you for your explanation,rn im not using sqlalchemy anymore,and fllow the code from your reference example,like this import pyodbc 
server = 'shul' 
database = 'PREDIKSIDB' 
username = 'prediksi' 
password = 'predik@2021si' 
Trusted_Connection='yes'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password +';Trusted='+Trusted_Connection)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
but when i try to send the data to sql, i got the same error.does it mean the problem is my password?

Comment: what should i do? should i change it? but i cant because its not mine

Answer (score 0):

You can study this link :

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

Set similar config :

```
   DATABASES = {
        "default": {
            "ENGINE": "sql_server.pyodbc",
            "NAME": env("database_name"),
            "USER": env("database_user"),
            "PASSWORD": env("database_password"),
            "HOST": env("database_host"),
            "PORT": env("database_port"),
            "OPTIONS": {
                "driver": "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
                "unicode_results": True,
            },
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you sir! im following the reference that you give,but its still error,do you think the problem is my password because its contain@? thank you again.